# Get brightness value from HSV - Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, filtering

how I can determine brightness value of a photo?
Here's my code, I can not understand how to determine it:

```
def rgb2hsv(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    return hsv
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A measure of brightness would be the average value of the V channel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by the *"brightness value"* of an image, but whatever you mean, it is stored in the **Value** channel (i.e. 3rd channel) of the **Hue, Saturation and Value** image you have already calculated.

So, if you want a single, mean brightness number for the whole image, you can use:

```
hsv[...,2].mean()
```

If you want a single, peak brightness number for the brightest spot in the image:

```
hsv[...,2].max()
```

And if you want a greyscale *"map"* of the brightness at each point of the image, just display or save the 3rd channel:

```
cv2.imwrite('brightness.png',hsv[...,2])
```

Comment: I would like to iterate every pixel and extract the brightness value and then do an average sum (all brightness value) / nPixels

Comment: @DaNio So, you want the first line of code I gave... `hsv[...,2].mean()`

Comment: Value corresponds strongly to brightness, but it is easy to see that with two HSV colours with the same H & V that changing the Saturation causes the brightness to change. And in fact changing Hue alone can impact brightness. It's probably easiest to convert to a grayscale image with cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY and check the brightness of that pixel.

Answer (score 1):

In HSV, 'value' is the brightness of the color and varies with color saturation. It ranges from 0 to 100%. When the value is ’0′ the color space will be totally black. With the increase in the value, the color space brightness up and shows various colors."

So use OpenCV method:

```
cvCvtColor(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, int code)
```

that converts an image from one color space to another. You may use:

```
code = CV_BGR2HSV
```

Then calculate histogram of third channel V, which is the brightness.

Probably it might help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need brightest pixel in the image use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(img_hsv)
bright_pixel = np.amax(v)
print(bright_pixel)
# bright_pixel will give max illumination value in the image
```